# Install Openstack on single node

Tags: openstack, centos8, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

I want to install Openstack on CentOS 8(single node). I am having single machine (physical machine) where I want to install all nodes of Openstack. This setup I required for simulation only not production use.
I have tried to install Openstack using packstac 3 times but couldn't success.
I got different issues during installation:
1.In first attempt After installation, I tried to create instance, but not getting console of instances even after it got created successfully.
2. In second attempt, during deployment of instance, network not getting allocated.
3. In third attempt, it got stuck at packstack, puppet testing only.

I have followed below 2 links:
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-openstack-victoria-on-centos/

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.linuxtechi.com/install-openstack-centos-8-with-packstack/amp/

I followed each and every steps mention in the likns.

I want to create two Ubuntu VMs on Openstack.

Can someone provide me some links/video, where I can get everything which is required to install Openstack on single node and create two Ubuntu VMs and assign network to them and test the connectivity between these two VMS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should notice that CentOS is no longer maintained, and this may cause problems in the future (such as dead repositories). Can you use a different distro?

Answer (score 1):

I would use official [Packstack documentation](https://www.rdoproject.org/install/packstack/). Note that you should start with a totally fresh Centos installation; i.e. don't try to install Packstack on a server where a previous installation failed (or succeeded).

You can also try [Devstack](http://docs.openstack.org/devstack). Its default configuration requires a smaller machine than Packstack (in my experience, 8GB RAM should be sufficient). Same remark: Start with a fresh installation of Centos or Ubuntu.

[Microstack](https://microstack.run/) is another alternative. Its advantage is a very simple and quick installation; its disadvantage is a very strange (in my opinion) configuration and not a lot of documentation. However, it is suitable for your purpose. It claims to work on any Linux, Windows and MacOS; it does require *snap*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest directly installation onto Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 1):

some time ago I wrote a serie of posts in which I explained in detail how to install OpenStack Rocky. The 2 first blog posts ([[1]](https://ilearnedhowto.wordpress.com/2019/02/25/how-to-install-openstack-rocky-part-1/) and [[2]](https://ilearnedhowto.wordpress.com/2019/03/25/how-to-install-openstack-rocky-part-2/)) contain commands, examples, content of configuration files that cover common scenarios and tips for the successful installation of most OpenStack services (keystone, nova, glance, etc.) in a single node, and the third post [[3]](https://ilearnedhowto.wordpress.com/2019/04/10/how-to-install-openstack-rocky-part-3-final/) describes the installation of a computing node. This 3rd post is installed in a different node for the sake of making it easier to understand how *nova* works, but the installation can be safely carried out in the same node than the other components.

I find that the posts are short enough and are very easy to follow (I use that blog as *my installation tips*, and so I have used them for several deployments). The only caveat is that it is based on Ubuntu, but if you know about your installation, it should be easy to translate the installation to CentOS (some colleagues have used these tips for CentOS installations).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Openstack several times last week (october 2021): a) with CentOS 8 Stream to metal hardware (real server) with devstack - no one version was installed (neither Master nor Xena & Wallaby, version Viktoria & below are not for Stream OS); b) Virtual machine with CentOS 8 Stream installed with packstack - installation was clearly successful (!), quite easy for install (according to official RDO project and its homepage), however there is the real problem with virtual and actual networking: no external network is accessible, router created was OK with external connection (router IP was detected successfully from outside) but no connection was possible from and to instance. So I conclude the Openstack package is not completely documented to resolve problems, however its installation can be quite easy (when successfully finish ;) )
Addition: Of coarse, there are resources with an information how network can be configured, official Openstack docs describes different network configurations as well (however it is difficult to find it for one click and being newbie), but anyway this system requires a lot of time to study before usage.